# Plotting Clusters after K-Means Clustering

Tags: python, scikit-learn, k-means

I have used K-Means Clustering on a dataset and I have found 7 clusters, but I am unable to plot the clusters. Please find below the code that I have used:-

```
# Plot the clustered data
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 10))
plt.scatter(general_population_scaled[kmeans.labels == 0, 0], general_population_scaled[kmeans.labels == 0, 1],
            c='green', label='cluster 1')
```

Please help me correct the code to generate results.This is the error I am getting:-

```
AttributeError: 'KMeans' object has no attribute 'labels'
```

Answer (score 0):

Cluster labels reside in the `labels_` attribute of the `kmeans` object, not the `labels` attribute

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html